# Will I be able to unlock Panna City Medicines now that the decoration special is finished?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I experienced the reset bug several times and my decorated levels were stripped (including when I had about 29 levels done ..so close!!!) so I was unable to unlock panna city meds.

Does anyone know if it will be possible to unlock this level some other way? I have special boba fett, but no level to match him with :,(

Answer (score 0):

As of this time, there is no other way to accomplish this.  It may become possible in a future update.